# Pass method as an argument

Tags: java

I have two similar methods:

```
public void methodOne() {
    final List<User> users = userService.getUsers();
    final Integer count = getCount();
    emailService.sendEmailOne(users, count);
}

public void methodTwo() {
    final List<User> users = userService.getUsers();
    final Integer count = getCount();
    emailService.sendEmailTwo(users, count);
}
```

The difference is - I'm sending different type of email. Can I pass method name as an argument here to get something like:

```
public void method(sendEmail) {
   final List<User> users = userService.getUsers();
    final Integer count = getCount();
    emailService.sendEmail(users, count);
}
```

Comment: You can use a `BiConsumer`: `public void method(BiConsumer<List<User>, Integer> sendEmail) { .... sendEmail.accept(users, count); .... }` and call it by passing `emailService::sendEmailOne`.

Answer (score 0):

The method headers in your first code snippet (e.g. `public void methodOne {`) are not syntactically correct. There are no parameter list after the method name.

To have the flexibility of choosing a method at runtime, you can create an `interface` with one abstract method, then implement it into two different classes and override it accordingly. Then you can use an instance of your interface as the parameter of `method`.

It should be something like this:

```
public interface Sender {
    abstract public void send();
}


public class SenderOne implements Sender {
    public void send() {
        // your implementation here
    }
}

public class SenderTwo implements Sender {
    public void send() {
        // your implementation here
    }
}
```

And finally:

```
public void method (Sender sender) {
    //...
    sender.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much faster and easier way to accomplish it.

This post here also includes some previous answers.

The first class declarations are just to make the example compilable.
The interesting parts start after the method `getCount()`

```
package snippet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class LamdaExample {
    // dummy declarations
    static class User {}
    static class EmailService {
        public void sendEmailOne(final List<User> pUsers, final Integer pCount) {}
        public void sendEmailTwo(final List<User> pUsers, final Integer pCount) {}
    }
    static class UserService {
        public List<User> getUsers() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public LamdaExample() {}
    private final UserService   userService     = new UserService();
    private final EmailService  emailService    = new EmailService();
    private Integer getCount() {
        return null;
    }

    // interesting part comes here

    public void methodOne() {
        System.out.println("LamdaExample.methodOne()");
        final List<User> users = userService.getUsers();
        final Integer count = getCount();
        emailService.sendEmailOne(users, count);
    }
    public void methodTwo() {
        System.out.println("LamdaExample.methodTwo()");
        final List<User> users = userService.getUsers();
        final Integer count = getCount();
        emailService.sendEmailTwo(users, count);
    }

    public void method(final Runnable sendEmail) {
        final List<User> users = userService.getUsers();
        final Integer count = getCount();
        sendEmail.run();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // simple runnable, see code above
        final LamdaExample t = new LamdaExample();
        t.method(() -> t.methodOne());
        t.method(() -> t.methodTwo());

        // extended special functional interface, see code below
        t.methodSpecial((p, q) -> t.methodX(p, q));
        t.methodSpecial((p, q) -> t.methodY(q, p));

    }

    // extended example starts here

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface MySpecialInterface {
        double specialMethod(String param1, Class<?> param2) throws IOException;
    }

    public void methodSpecial(final MySpecialInterface sendEmail) {
        final List<User> users = userService.getUsers();
        final Integer count = getCount();

        try {
            sendEmail.specialMethod("lol", this.getClass());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public double methodX(final String pP, final Class<?> pQ) {
        System.out.println("LamdaExample.methodX()");
        final List<User> users = userService.getUsers();
        final Integer count = getCount();
        emailService.sendEmailOne(users, count);
        return 123.456;
    }
    public double methodY(final Class<?> pQ, final String pP) {
        System.out.println("LamdaExample.methodY()");
        final List<User> users = userService.getUsers();
        final Integer count = getCount();
        emailService.sendEmailTwo(users, count);
        return 98.765;
    }


}
```